# Flurry get user journey for all users in segment

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

In user journey section of flurry it shows 20 user journeys for my custom segment but i am sure that the size of this segment is very bigger than this.
Is there any way that i can get all user journeys from specific segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Journeys only pull a sample of the available journeys. There is no setting available to pull all journeys.